Shader to RGB node not working with GLOSSY shader in 4.2
So, I basically use Glossy with Shader to Rgb for reflection many times, and I checked blender 4.2 today and the method I uses is not working anymore.
I don't know why (and yes ray tracing is enable and I am still not getting any reflections "with shader to rgb").
please help.


I do not know what kind of 4.0 you have there, but I tested it on my PC with Blender 3.6.9, 4.0.2, 4.1.1 and 4.2, the behaviour is consistent in all versions. As soon as I plug the Shader to RGB node inbetween, the reflection disappears. The only reflections the Shader to RGB node shows is the environment (grey in your case or an HDRI in my case). And this still works in 4.2, so I cannot see any change.

It is a bug: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/123017

I forgot to mention I am using a light prob - reflection plane on both side.
